# Visual Studio intellisense class suggestion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

Is it possible to make Visual Studio list all classes, and not just the ones from the imported namespaces? The only way I know of auto-importing types this way is to type in the class name exactly right, then right-click and import. Something like Eclipse, which can list all available classes as you are typing.

Comment: Tip: You don't have to take your hands off the keyboard to import a namespace once you've typed the class name, you can type Ctrl + . (period) and press Enter.

Comment: @Zach: Awesomeness. Not sure how I missed that for years, but I like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about Intellisense.

There's always the Object Browser.

Comment: The Object Browser doesn't show the types from included assemblies, it would seem.

Comment: It will if you select "My Solution" from the drop-down box labelled "Browse:"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here: [Is it possible for Intellisense to search for classes in unimported namespaces like in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149659/is-it-possible-for-intellisense-to-search-for-classes-in-unimported-namespaces-l)

You may use the IntelliSense Extender Plugin. For Visual Studio 2017:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntelliSenseExtender

And for VS 2019:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntellisenseExtender2019

It includes the types of all projects in the solution and of all referenced packages. Selecting an not imported type from IntelliSense will then auto import that type.