# How to get Intellisense to automatically resolve missing Using directives

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, xna, intellisense

I have just installed VS2010 in order to do some XNA development and I have noticed, coming from using Eclipse on a day to day basis, that one very useful feature appears to be missing. When I start typing a class name from another namespace, intellisense doesn't display it so I cannot autocomplete. I have to type in the full name, hover over the typed class name with my cursor, then click the menu that appears in order for the using directive to be added.

Is there a way to get a similar behaviour like in Eclipse where it shows all class names in the current project and automatically adds the import when you autocomplete?

Comment: You have to reference the DLL before the intellisense appears, I'd be interested if there was a tool that automatically added the ref. Eg type `ConfigurationManager` and for the System.Configuration.DLL to be automagically added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio intellisense class suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698814/visual-studio-intellisense-class-suggestion)

Comment: That'd be a nice feature to have. FYI, you can skip the mouse and hit `ctrl+.` to bring up a quick context menu and then hit `enter` to include the using statement.

Comment: If my memory serves me right, Eclipse does not automatically include intellisense for classes that are not in any imported packages. It does have the ability to import them after you have written the name right, though. This is achieved in VS by using [Ctrl]+[.], as mentioned in other comment.

Answer (score 1):

you must use visual studio + resharper.
Resharper is the best addin for vs. It's a productivity booster! Although it's not free, It's worth it and there's also a free 30 days trial.
When you start working with resharper, you can't leave it.
Also, i recommend you to use stylecop too. It's an open soucee code rule validations and enforcement