# Is it possible for Intellisense to search for classes in unimported namespaces like in Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, intellisense

In Eclipse, autocomplete works even for unused packages or namespaces. That means that if I have a class named DuckWrapper in a package, and in a class that didn't import the package DuckWrapper I press ctrl+space, it will display DuckWrapper and automatically import its package if necessary.

Visual Studio however, doesn't show it in its autocompletion unless I added it first to the using list.

Can that be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be changed in a standard installation of Visual Studio, so you would need to install an extension to add the feature. One commonly used extension which provides this feature is [JetBrain's ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Import_Symbol_Completion). Here is a quote from their documentation.

> Import Symbol Completion (formerly Type Name Completion) is invoked with Ctrl+Alt+Space. Unlike Symbol Completion (which only completes types accessible at the current location), ReSharper displays all types that match a specified prefix regardless of what namespace they belong to, and automatically adds the appropriate namespace import directives when necessary. In C# code files, Import Symbol Completion works after dot with extension methods and puts necessary using directives.

[image: Import Symbol Completion]

Comment: Thanks, I kind of feared that. Strange that such a normal feature isn't featured in vanilla VS.

Comment: resharper is extremely heavy, it's an education tool for beginners

Comment: Outdated with VS2019. See answers below

Answer (score 16):

This kind of feature exists in current version of Visual Studio 2019 but it is still experimental.

[image: IntelliSense without this feature on]

As you can see in the image above, you can't see the entity `Student` from the namespace Test2 that's in another project but if you click button in the bottom left corner of IntelliSense window, you will see this.

[image: IntelliSense with this feature on]

Upon accepting Student option that IntelliSense gives, all needed namespaces will automatically be added at the top of your file (or bellow all the existing using statements above the namespace name).

You can turn this option on/off in:

- *Tools*
- *Options*
- *Text Editor*
- *C#*
- *IntelliSense*
- *Check/Uncheck the last option 'Show items from unimported namespaces (experimental)*

EDIT: I embedded the images instead of just hyperlinking them.

Comment: Hey, maybe embed the images here so people can see them in the answer instead of being taken offsite to some other location that they do not know about.

Comment: @williampatton I dont think I can post images unless I have certain amount of reputation, but I sadly, do not have it. Images are located on stack overflow's imgur account and it shouldn't be a problem for anyone to open. Alternatively, here's a google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tN98lZoXE9bhXvDCbyZ3G3KR7XKHao7h?usp=sharing).

Comment: Ahh fair point @Dacha, should have realised image upload permissions would not be granted yet. I can confirm the offsite location is safe. Thanks for adding an additional answer for this question :) Edit: upvoted, you should have enough rep to embed images now.

Comment: @WilliamPatton Thanks for the help, I embedded the images now :) Cheers

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 - still doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 9):

You may use the IntelliSense Extender Plugin.
For Visual Studio 2017:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntelliSenseExtender

And for VS 2019:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntellisenseExtender2019

It includes the types of all projects in the solution and of all referenced packages. Selecting an not imported type from IntelliSense will then auto import that type.